# biblatex: bbl wrong format version

Tags: biblatex, errors, biber

I am using texlive 2012, and both pdflatex and biber are executed with full path to ensure the correct binary.

biblatex has version 2.2, biber 0.9.9.

If I run pdflatex, biber, pdflatex I get the following output of biber

```
INFO - This is Biber 0.9.9
INFO - Logfile is 'LaTeXTemplate.blg'
INFO - Reading 'LaTeXTemplate.bcf'
WARN - Warning: Found biblatex control file version 2.0, expected version 1.7
INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
```

and in the end I get the error from pdflatex

```
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data...
Package biblatex Warning: File 'LaTeXTemplate.bbl' is wrong format version - expected 2.1.

Package biblatex Info: ... file 'LaTeXTemplate.bbl' found.
(./LaTeXTemplate.bbl
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...c@refsection @entry@\blx@slist@name
```

What is going wrong ? I already deleted all biblatex and the aux file, but it is reproducible. 
Why is the bcf and bbl file version expected wrong?

Comment: biber 0.9.9 isn't compatible with biblatex 2.2. Use tlmgr to upgrade biber 1.2. For a list of compatible releases refer to table 1 in the biblatex manual.

Comment: When I restarted the editor the correct biber (1.2) was used, though the path to the binary is the same. Strange. It works now.